# Are there restrictions on carrying fresh produce across US state borders?

Tags: usa, legal, washington-state

I'm planning on traveling from one US state to another (by plane, in this case) with fresh produce.

I know that importing fresh produce internationally is subject to restrictions.  A quick googling seems to imply that it's generally okay domestically, but there is mention of exceptions, particularly CA, WA, and HI.  Since I'm travelling to WA, this concerns me.  Where can I confirm any such restrictions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These normally are handled by the states department of Agriculture and are usually related to plants but if you're concerned with what you're bringing in first advice would be: Don't bring it with you.  Second would be check the quarantine list and requirements from [Washington States Department of Agriculture](http://agr.wa.gov/PlantsInsects/PlantQuarantines/PlantQuarantines.aspx)

Comment: +1.  It may not be obvious at first glance, but a lot of the entries in the quarantine list do restrict the produce, not only the plants.